# How to control Adobe Flash Player in Internet Explorer with keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer-9, flash-player, media-keys

I'm using Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421 with Adobe Flash Player 11.3.300.270.

Recently I'm listening a lot to music from YouTube (mostly due to exploring new "territories"). But there is one thing that annoys me: it is lack of control over the player when IE window is not active.

With "offline player" (like for example foobar2000) I can pause/resume, go to next/previous and so on using configured keyboard shortcuts. Those shortcuts (if made "global") work even if some other window is active.

How to achieve that with Flash Player in IE? At best I would like to use media keys on my keyboard. (They do work with Flash Player but only if IE window is active and inside of it the Flash Player is active.) But other shortcuts would do as well.

Comment: Since it looks like I'm not going to get answers here I asked the same question on MSDN Forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/87dfb9d6-f973-4ea7-a441-1a3f0dd49f37.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible!

But a solution would be to use a [player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_player_%28application_software%29) that is not embedded within [IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer).
For example, [Umplayer](http://www.umplayer.com/features/) which can search, record and play [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/) video's
would allow you to set global shortcuts to your multimedia keys.

Comment: How do you know it is not possible? How about writing a plug-in for IE or something like that?

Comment: Even if you could get the source for adobe flash, and hook into it, once IE looses focus you'd be right back where you started.

Comment: I checked UMPlayer. It does play from YouTube (yet when I opened link somehow it didn't work, but search did). BUT: (1) There is just an option to play a single file. No suggestions for other similar files. An option which is crucial (for me) on the site since that is the "exploring" aspect. (This way I could very well just download the clips...) (2) I did not found a way to make the shortcuts global, they work only if UMPlayer is active. (3) I did not found a way to bind to multimedia keys.